# ASP.NET MVC 4 Authorization for same user or else Admin

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

Hi i want to put a authorization filter on a action method in my controller that can be access by the same user or else admin.

suppose  there a user Alex registers to my website and now want to edit his profile. so he should be allowed to edit only his profile not others or Admin will have rights to edit everyone's profile.

I can add role as admin in the Authorize attribute but how to tackle the self user thing. kindly help

```
[Authorize(Roles="admin")]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of an authorization filter that would check if the user name (it can be GUID or any other method) matches the parameter passed to the route and checks for user role on Admin

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;  // if user not Authenticated, do not allow

        string userName = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        string id = filterContext.RouteData.Values[this.RouteParameter];

        If (userName == id)
            return true;  // assuming paramter passed matches username, allow
        else if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole( "Admin" ) || IsOwner( filterContext ))
            return true;  // if user has role Admin, allow


        return true;
    }
}
```

While this is untested and meant to guide more than solve your need, I think it will come close to an implementation.

Meanwhile, I'd like to add my 2 cents on your approach:

I am more in favor of an Action Filter that would do a similar check and redirect the user to their own page or to a warning page. While I value the security Authorization Filter provide, I find them to be rather blunt. I prefer permission based security and soft redirects that provide a more elegant user experience.

Comment: @Dave Alperovich Where you got 'filterContext' and 'IsOwner' from?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in my change password so that only that user can change his/her own password.
 In my **Account controller**

```
    //
    // GET: /Account/ChangePassword
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/ChangePassword
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (MembershipService.ChangePassword(User.Identity.Name, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword))
                return RedirectToAction("ChangePasswordSuccess");
            else
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

then in my in **_Layout** I declare it like this so that only that user can see and open that ActionLink and change his/her own password

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Change Password", "ChangePassword", "Account")</li>                     
   }
```

Hope this will also help you.. Cheers. :)